# Unable to insert and save an escaped double quote in MySQL

Tags: mysql, json, escaping

I am trying to save JSON values in MySQL, but everytime the value contains double quotes, even if the query is properly written, MySQL manages to removed the escaped `\"`

For example:

```
INSERT into JSON_VALUES SET
ID = 150,
RESULT = '[{"ID":"150","VALUE":"THIS IS A \"TEST\" THAT IS IGNORED","DATE":"2021-08-26"}]'
```

After executing the query the inserted value in MySQL looks like this:

```
[{
"ID":"150",
"VALUE":"THIS IS A "TEST" THAT IS IGNORED",
"DATE":"2021-08-26"
}]
```

When `"TEST"` was supposed to be saved as `\"TEST\"`
Since TEST is not properly escpaed, the JSON value has a syntax error and becomes unreadable.

How do I force MySQL to preserve escaped content, or more precisely escaped double quotes?

Comment: Answered in [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/159675) on [dba.se]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue some time ago. I had to use `\\\"` instead of `\"`. In your case would be:

```
INSERT into JSON_VALUES SET
ID = 150,
RESULT = '[{"ID":"150","VALUE":"THIS IS A \\\"TEST\\\" THAT IS IGNORED","DATE":"2021-08-26"}]'
```